# android- How to launch an app from your app in android

Tags: android

Im trying to launch an application from another one. Ive used the fingerpaint api demo and added a save and some different brushes and Id like the user to be prompted on saving the picture to select something like photoshop to do color correction of photomanipulation to the photo and once they are done with the photo and its saved in photoshop have the fingerpaint app reopen with the photo they just manipulated in the screen and ready for them to add more to if they chose to do so.

Will I have to set a background activity to read the photoshops state and when it saves? Thats what Im thinking I will have to do but Im not sure at this point.

Im not asking for some one to code it out for me but if any one has an idea of how or where I can see an example of an app opening another that would be awesome.

( and please do not be so vague as to say look at the android.com dev section as there is WAY to much info to look through on there. I spend half my day on there already :p )

Comment: Once you start another app, you have no control over what happens to the control flow of the activity states. So you can't expect to open photoshop, and then be notified when the user saves. That's just not possible.

Comment: One way to handle your requirement is to expect the user to save the photo in the same file. You can keep polling for the time-stamp changes for the file from a service in your app. Once you see any changes in the file show a notification to the user from which the user can open the photo in your app. You will have to be careful in taking care of unnecessary polling and locking the file.

Comment: So the background activity I would set to monitor the photoshop app would basically be polling for changes in the picture file created by the user?  Ok Im pretty sure I know what your telling me but Ill definitely need to do some testing to see if what I want will totally slow down the phone......thats the last thing I want is my app to be known as a phone lagger :p  Let me see if I can at least get the app to open photoshop with the picture that the user created and then Ill take it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) are used to launch other activities. Best way would be to save the image and get the uri for the image.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT, imageUri);
this.startActivity(i);
```

That will launch whatever activity that can handle that uri and intent type. You can also use [createChooser](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#createChooser%28android.content.Intent,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) to give the user the option to pick an Activity. (similar to have the share option works in most apps).

To do the saving recognition I'm not sure if [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) would do what you want. it depends on how the Photoshop app is setup.

Comment: Ok....so once the user saves the image I can just use the images uri in a new intent and android will automatically choose the apps suitable for that type of uri? I'm going to try it out and let you guys know what I get to work.  Thanks for the tip though.